# How to load the Google StreetViewCoverageLayer under iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, google-street-view

My iOS app uses StreetView panoramas.
To let a user select a route that is covered by StreetView, I want to overlay a Google Map with the StreetView coverage.
Such a layer is provided in the Google JavaScript SDK by the `StreetViewCoverageLayer` class, [see here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/street-view#StreetViewCoverageLayer).
Unfortunately, this class seems not to be available in the iOS SDK.
As a workaround, I am trying to integrate Javascript code in my iOS app, following [this excellent tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/javascriptcore-swift/).
So, my JavaScript code is called, but raises an exception (as expected).

Here is my iOS  code:

```
func initializeJS() {
    jsContext = JSContext()    

    // Add an exception handler.
    self.jsContext.exceptionHandler = { context, exception in
        if let exc = exception {
            print("JS Exception:", exc.toString()!)
        }
    }
    
    // Specify the path to the jssource.js file.
    if let jsSourcePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "JavaScript", ofType: "js") {
        do {
            // Load its contents to a String variable.
            let jsSourceContents = try String(contentsOfFile: jsSourcePath)
            
            // Add the Javascript code that currently exists in the jsSourceContents to the Javascript Runtime through the jsContext object.
            jsContext.evaluateScript(jsSourceContents)
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }    
}

func jsDemo1() {
    if let getStreetViewCoverageLayer = self.jsContext.objectForKeyedSubscript("getStreetViewCoverageLayer") {
        if let result = getStreetViewCoverageLayer.call(withArguments: nil) {
            print(result.toString()!)
        }
    }
```

And here is the test JavaScript code:

```
function getStreetViewCoverageLayer() {
    var streetViewLayer = new google.maps.StreetViewCoverageLayer();
    return "getStreetViewCoverageLayer"
}
```

When I run the app, it calls the JavaScript exception handler, and prints

```
JS Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google
```

which is clear since `google` is not defined. Of course I know that I should contact the Google server first with something like

```
'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3' + '&key=<MY_API_KEY>&callback=initialize'
```

**My question is:**
How do I do this in my JavaScript code?

Comment: There is already an open feature request entry for this in Google Public Issue Tracker. You can check it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/35828626

Comment: @jabamataro Thanks for the hint. I wrote a supporting comment.